# Restrict & Redirect Visitors Based on IP in WordPress Site

Tags: php, geolocation, wordpress

I'm trying to build an intranet type site for a client using WordPress as the base. Instead of having users sign in, they just want to restrict users by IP address. They also want certain sets of IPs to be able to only access certain sections of the site.

So, I was wondering if there were any plugins or anything that addressed this type of setup already? I'm trying to not do this from scratch if I can help it.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Server side configuration. Maybe combination of firewall, iptables and the webserver restriction.

Comment: The server should actually restrict access from outside, but there would still be some section to section restrictions needed for the IPs that are allowed to access the server as a whole.

I was kind of looking for a coding option for the direction & access for routing the different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the free IP2Location Country Block WordPress Plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip2location-country-blocker/

It can restrict visitors by IP address block (country).